# Is there any method to let python (module requests) not load full webpage when using get method?

Tags: python

Not sure if the title make sense or not. Let me give more details here: I use **requests** module to get some webpages and then use **BeautifulSoup** or **re** to parse them. Those pages are kind of big ones, it will take a little while to get them. After taking a look at the HTMLs, I found that all information I care about resides in the first couple of lines (say the first 100 lines) of the HTML. So my question is that if there is a method to load those first 100 lines ONLY when using **requests.get** method?

P.S. The **requests** module is not mandatory here. If the problem can be solved without this module, I'm OK with it. Many thx.

Comment: Are you sure you can parse it as correct HTML if you just get a truncated chunk?

Comment: BeautifulSoup won't, but I believe using regular expression should do.

Comment: [`HTTPResponse.read()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#httpresponse-objects) accepts a parameter specifying the number of bytes to be read. Read however many bytes you need then close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

The requests package supports precisely this with its `readlines()` function:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://google.com', stream=True)
first_five_lines = r.raw.readlines(5)
print ''.join(first_five_lines)
```